# Why are media items no longer available at /media/{id}?

Tags: media, 10

I'm using the Media module, but I noticed there isn't a path like /media/%id where I can see the media and its fields.

The only path available seems to be media/%id/edit and media/%id/delete.

On Drupal 8, it was possible to access a media page. What's wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This was an announced change that released in Drupal 8.7.0—["Media items no longer available at /media/{id}"](https://www.drupal.org/node/3018742). The change added a new setting to enable the "id" route and turned it on for existing sites. New sites must have the setting enabled at /admin/config/media/media-settings.

Answer (score 2):

**Steps: To enable this '/media/%id' path:**: In Drupal9/10

Enable the 'Media' module and then go to this page:
your_site_url/admin/config/media/media-settings

Enable this checkbox 'Standalone media URL'

**Additonal info:**

**#1: Basically this route '/media/%id' disabled by core.**

#2: May be in your case module 'Media' enabled, you just need to enable  this checkbox 'Standalone media URL' and save the form.